# Forgot Password Request (Java)

Tags: java, passwords, token, reset, uuid

Quite a common subject for most of you guys. I'm building a webapp in Java, using Spring + Spring Security + Hibernate + MySQL + etc...

I'm in the process of implementing the "reset password" module. I already know the process flow and have all the forms and corresponding controllers. I just would like to know, before writing code all over the place, if I'm starting with the right foot and then continue improving it.

**MySQL table** :

```
PASSWORD_CHANGE_REQUESTS ( 
       TOKEN VARCHAR(126) NOT NULL,
       USERNAME VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,         
       CREATION_TIME DATETIME NOT NULL,        
       PRIMARY KEY(TOKEN)          
)
```

I've seen that some posts recommend a EXPIRE_DATE field. Is it really worth it?

**Unique token:**

I'm using a Spring SHA encoder with username + timestamp as parameters (+ required salt value) which returns strings such as: *92c303b9740da5959418c32d04b6ec6f4ca61637*.

Does this method really generate a **unique token** for the URL? Or is there a better way to do it?

In Java, the timestamp is generated like this:

```
 Date date = new Date();
 SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss");
 String timestamp = sdf.format(date);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I say add the field EXPIRE_DATE to DB.
1-For expediency you might need the EXPIRE_DATE field in order to perform a select and check for validity in one swoop when you verify and validate the token against the values in the Database.
2-For Database cleanup you can easily truncate expired records by running simply script.

You can also validate that the token has not expired in application layer by checking against the current time but that is seems more cumbersome. Also DB cleanup would depend on some application logic or script logic to determine whether a record is expired and ready for removal.

That Spring HSA encoder should work for your purposes, however its use is primarily to encode password and not to generate unique tokens. For unique tokens you could check out Java UUID

and you can read more here

[How to generate a random alpha-numeric string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41107/how-to-generate-a-random-alpha-numeric-string-in-java)

and

[HTTP URL token standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3889809/http-url-token-standard)

Comment: Thanks for the info. You and Marc just gave me the confirmation I needed for the expiration field. By the way, I already implemented the UUID function. Thanks also for the links!

Answer (score 1):

Expiration of password change requests can be useful in case a hacker gains control of a users e-mail and finds one of these links. If the user doesn't use that e-mail account anymore with your system, at least it'll protect them from having their password reset in your system since the request will likely have expired. Obviously if they gain control of an e-mail account that is used for your system, the expiration won't do much good because they can simply request a reset again. Either way, it's a relatively simple thing you can do to provide additional security for your users.

In terms of generating a unique token, I think your strategy is pretty good. To make it even more difficult to generate a conflicting token, you can use something like `System.nanoTime()` or `System.currentTimeMillis()` to get a time with more precision. Your current method means if it is called within the same second, you'll get a non-unique token. While that's probably rare, it's considerably more so with milliseconds or nanoseconds.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I already added the expiration date column. You're right, it will add a little more security plus I won't have to calculate it every time. About the timestamp, of course, milliseconds/nanoseconds... I realized about that when I started clicking faster and the token didn't change at the same time. Now it's ok.

Comment: As @myqyl4 mentioned in his answer, you can use Java UUID as well. Most likely either is going to work for you just fine. UUID is a very safe way to generate unique identifiers and in something like 252 million years, `System.currentTimeMillis()` is going to overflow and break your unique ID generator. ;)

Comment: As another measure of security, it might help to either delete password change requests after they are used, or at least mark them as used. That will add an additional level of security.

Comment: Yeah, I already had that in mind. Though I still don't know if I'll do both (mark as used, then run a script and delete all marked) or directly delete the record :D